# Gettings list from web service/ array list in android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have an application which gets a list of items from a web service. The web services replies as

```
"1234: Apple \n 3456:LINUX \n 5543:Windows \n"
```

While on client side I am receiving the data as

```
1234: Apple
3456: LINUX
5543: Windows
```

Now I want each item to be clickable like when I click first item i.e Apple a new activity should be started. What will be the best way to do it. I think I should save it to an array list but not sure what to do with it and how to make each item clickable.

here is my code of Asynctask.

```
  public void getlist(String list_type) {

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_LIST);


PropertyInfo typePI = new PropertyInfo();
typePI.setName("type");
typePI.setValue(list_type);
typePI.setType(double.class);

request.addProperty(typePI);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_LIST, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    ServerResponse = response.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}           
  }


public class getlist extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    list(type);
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.i("List Ressults", "onPostExecute");
    if (ServerResponse==null) {
        tv.setText("Please Try again"); // no response from server SOAP error/ server refused the connection.
    }
    tv.setText(ServerResponse);
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.i("List Results", "onPreExecute");
    tv.setText("Please Wait...");
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    Log.i("List Ressults", "onProgressUpdate");
}
```

My ultimate requirement is to make all the items clickable.

here os logcat

```
  12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356): java.lang.NullPointerException
  12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):   at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116) 
  12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):   at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
  12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):   at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
  12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):   at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
  12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):   at com.myapp.listvie.Promotions.onCreateView(Promotions.java:74)
  12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
  12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
 12-23 12:38:26.295: E/AndroidRuntime(2356):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array if string out of this response

```
String list=ServerResponse.split("\n");
```

Now create an array adapter and set this array to it.
Put a list view in layout and set this adapter to that list.

In the and add on item click listener to your listview and put your actions in that.

Answer (score 0):

implements OnItemClickListener interface and for list use arrayadapter

Inside onCreateView()  Method  :

result is your response

```
 JSONArray responseinArray = new JSONArray(responseInString);
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < responseinArray .length(); i++) {
            try {
                listItems
                        .add(responseinArray .getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString(BsharpConstant.NAME_CONSTANT)
                                .toString());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

listOfProduct is :

```
ListView listOfProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idOfUrView);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         ActivityName.this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
         listOfProducts.setAdapter(adapter);
                     listOfProducts.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Implements OnItemClickListener interface and use this code:

```
        @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    String clickedItemName = (String) listOfProductsCategory
            .getItemAtPosition(position);
    int clickedItemId = (int) listOfProductsCategory
            .getItemIdAtPosition(position);

    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),
            "Product is getting load : " + clickedItemName,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //call your method if u want
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing it like this as @vipul mittal said but list view is not populating. 
String[] list={};
ServerResponse = response.toString();
  for (int i = 0; i < ServerResponse.length(); i++) {
   
   list =ServerResponse.split("\n");
  }
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
  listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
listView1 = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Comment: Are u able to construct the ArrayList or not??

Comment: Paste ur response here

Comment: this is server response 
 91001430:Free 750 Package
 91001431:525 Package
 91001432: 425 Package (10pm to 10am)
 91001433:425 Package (11pm to 11am)
 91001434:Package (12pm to 12am)
 91000000:Loyalty Package
 91000080:White Plus Package
 91002600:Power Package

Comment: this is in JSONArray or JSONObject??

Comment: have no idea I am just calling the web service and this is the response.

Comment: use this : 
if response in string format
    
   JSONArray response = new JSONArray(responseInString);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43775/discussion-between-rup35h-and-rida-shahid)

Comment: I have edited the question. 
I have imported a library for onitmeclicklisner. after that its not working.

Comment: Same question again r u able construst the ArrayList or not or getting error while clicking the item?

Comment: No array list is not creating. The application crashes and forced closed while clicking the activity.

Comment: have u tried 
     JSONArray responseinArray = new JSONArray(responseInString);

Comment: if u r getting the response in String use above and if in String array then directly
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < responseinArray .length(); i++) {
            try {
                listItems
                        .add(responseinArray[i]);
                                
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: ServerResponse = response.toString()
list =ServerResponse.split("\n");
public void onClick(View v) {
AsyncPL promotion_list = new AsyncPL();
promotion_list.execute();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
I have tried this it works but list view is created when I press the button two times. :( @rup35h any hint? :(